# Counting characters in a file stream

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function how_many(), which counts the number of characters of a certain type, say "\n" or ",", in a file stream. Here is my (failed) attempt:

```
int how_many(char mychar, anifstream myfile){
    int result;
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
       if(myfile.get()==mychar){result=result+1;}
    }
    myfile.close(); // Closes the filestream "my file"
    return result; 
}
```

First question: is "\n" a character or a string? (If so, then I should make the first input a string instead of a character)

Second question: can you explain the resulting error message? (or alternatively, directly point out the misuse of syntax in my code):

```
 warning: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified
  (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
 note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [2]' to
  'char' for 1st argument
```

Comment: which version of C++ are you targeting ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the same code that produces this error?

Comment: Search Stackoverflow for "c++ bad eof", as to why you should not use `eof`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"\n"` is a string literal that has type `const char[2]` and contains two characters: `'\n'` and `'\0'`.

`'\n'` - is an escape character literal that has type `char`.

Take into account that variable `result` in your function was not initialized.

Comment: I fail to see how anything in these answer "fixes" anything, accurate though its statements are.

Comment: Also, the `myfile.eof` is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` is a char, whereas `"\n"` is a string literal (of type `const char[2]` last one for null )

For counting prefer algorithm

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
//..

std::size_t result = std::count( std::istream_iterator<char>(myfile), 
                                 std::istream_iterator<char>(),
                                  mychar 
                                ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make a histogram, while you are reading the file:

```
std::vector<char> character_counts(256); // Assuming ASCII characters

// ...

char c;
while (cin >> c) // The proper way to read in a character and check for eof
{
  character_counts[c]++; // Increment the number of occurances of the character.
}
```

In the case you posted, you could find the number of '\n' by:

```
cout << "Number of \'\\n\' is: " << character_counts['\n'] << endl;
```